# How does google books highlight text in a scanned image

Tags: hit-highlighting

If I do a keyword search here:

http://books.google.com/ebooks/reader?id=s1gVAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&pg=GBS.PA7

The highlighted text in the "flowing text" seems easy enough but if you switch to show "scanned pages" it still shows the highlighted text?  Anybody know how they accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through an OCR process, either when they scanned the image or dynamically when you request the page.

Comment: so do they use XY coordinates to line up the highlighted word on the image since the scanned image itself is only a representation of text and not actually text.  I understand that for search and "flowing text" to work there was an OCR process

Comment: Yes, most OCR processes will output the character it recognized with a coordinate (typically a rectangle) so you know what's being displayed and where it's located on the image. Using those coordinates it can then paint a box over the phrase to highlight.